# The echo function in shell (zsh) and the capture of parentheses

Tags: linux, shell, escaping, zsh

I've created a little script so that I can quickly append some text to a file in Dropbox.

The code:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $(date +%d/%m/%Y) $*>>/home/guillaume/Dropbox/note.txt
```

The function works as intended. When, in the terminal, I type:

```
$pc-guillaume$ note 123
```

`20/01/2015 123` is appended to `note.txt`

But it doesn't work if there are parentheses in the arguments passed to the `note` function.

For instance, if I type:

```
$pc-guillaume$ note 123(
```

I get

```
>
```

And if I type:

```
$pc-guillaume$ note ()
```

I get:

```
function>
```

How could I modify my script to make it able to capture literal parentheses?

Comment: Quote it: `echo $(date +%d/%m/%Y) "$@" >>/home/guillaume/Dropbox/note.txt`

Comment: I tried your solution `$pc-guillaume$ note (123)` and got `zsh: no matches found: (123)`

Comment: My mistake! I thought bash and zsh were not too different on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user needs to add quotes when calling your script:

```
$ note "123("
```

Otherwise, your script is never started or run, because the shell is still looking for user input -- so, for that reason, there's nothing you can change in your script that would modify this behavior; it's not yet in control at the point in time at hand.

---

One thing you *could* do is change the calling convention. If your script were instead called like so:

```
$ note
123(
^D
```

...then you'd have no problem. (The `^D` is referring to typing ctrl+D, the end-of-file character, but the implementation below also treats just pressing enter with no input as an end-of-input).

You might implement this like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r line && [ "$line" ]; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$(date +%d/%m/%Y)" "$line"
done >>/home/guillaume/Dropbox/note.txt
```

If you don't worry about cases where the date changes while the program is being run, you might run the `date` command only once, rather than eating the efficiency of running it once per line. Another optimization would be to take advantage of built-in functionality in modern shells (certainly bash 4.3, can't speak to zsh) for date formatting built into `printf` rather than needing the overhead of an external process invocation at all. So, an efficient version taking advantage of modern bash functionality (only for systems with a very new release of bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Warning: This requires Bash 4.3
while IFS= read -r && [[ $REPLY ]]; do
  printf '%(%d/%m/%Y)T %s\n' -1 "$REPLY"
done >>/home/guillaume/Dropbox/note.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your implementation and, since I'm rather new on Linux and programming in general, I'll use *The Linux Command Line*, from William E. Schotts to understand what it does in detail.

Comment: The reference I most strongly suggest is the BashGuide and associated FAQ at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ; these are actively maintained resources by the folks in the freenode #bash IRC channel (who, while sometimes prickly, do care deeply about accuracy). There's rather an unfortunately large number of very poorly written and edited (often, outright inaccurate) books on bash, though I can't speak to that one in particular. (The ABS, or "advanced" bash scripting guide, is another resource that has lots of Google juice but is oft inaccurate).

Comment: BashFAQ #1 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 -- will start you on the way to understanding how this answer works.